# unable to animate the random squence of points using webgl, the window only updates at the end of animation

Tags: javascript, animation, webgl

```
// vertex shader source
var VSHADER_SRC =   'attribute vec4 a_Position;'+'\n'+
                    'attribute vec4 a_Color;'+'\n'+
                    'varying vec4 v_Color;'+'\n'+
                    'attribute float a_PointSize;'+'\n'+
                    'void main(){'+'\n'+
                    '   gl_Position = a_Position;'+'\n'+
                    '   gl_PointSize = a_PointSize;'+'\n'+
                    '   v_Color = a_Color;'+'\n'+
                    '}'+'\n';         

// fragment shader source
var FSHADER_SRC =   'precision mediump float;'+'\n'+
                    'varying vec4 v_Color;'+'\n'+
                    'void main(){'+'\n'+
                    '   gl_FragColor = v_Color;'+'\n'+
                    '}'+'\n';

var a_Position;
var a_PointSize;
var a_Color;

var vertexBuffer;

var FSIZE;

// webgl context
var gl;

var canvas;

// id of requestAnimationFrame
var animationID;

function main(){
    // retriving canvas element
    canvas = document.getElementById('drawing_canvas');
    if(!canvas){
        console.log('unable to retrive canvas element');
    }

    // setting width and height
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    // getting webgl context from canvas
    gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
    if(!gl){
        console.log('unable to retrive webgl context');
    }

    // initializing shaders
    if(!initShaders(gl,VSHADER_SRC,FSHADER_SRC)){
        console.log('unable to initialize shaders');
    }

    // getting locations of attributes and uniform variables
    a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program,'a_Position');
    a_PointSize = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program,'a_PointSize');
    a_Color = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program,'a_Color');


    if(a_Position<0){
        console.log('unable to retrive location of a_Position from shader programs');
    }
    if(a_PointSize<0){
        console.log('unable to retrive location of a_PointSize from shader programs');
    }
    if(a_Color<0){
        console.log('unable to retrive location of a_Color from shader programs');
    }

    // initializing buffers
    vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    if(!vertexBuffer){
        console.log('unable to create vertex buffer');
    }

    // binding buffer object to ARRAY_BUFFER
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);

    // starting animation
    animate = function(){
        animationID = requestAnimationFrame(animate,canvas);
        draw();
    };
    animationID = requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){
        points.push(-1+Math.random()*2,1-Math.random()*2,5.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
        n+=1;
        sleep(10);
    }

}

// to stop execution for a few miliseconds
function sleep(miliseconds) {
   var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

   while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {
   }
}

/**
 *Data about all the shapes stored in this variable
 *form of the data will be
 *x coordinate,y coordinate,pointsize,color(RGB)
 */
var points = [];
// number of shapes
var n=0;

var check = false;


function draw(){
    // clearing the canvas for drawing
    gl.clearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // getting data in webgl supported format
    vertices = new Float32Array(points);
    FSIZE = vertices.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;

    // passing data to buffers
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,vertices,gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    // passing data to a_Position attribute
    if(!check){
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Position,2,gl.FLOAT,false,FSIZE*6,0);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);

        // passing data to a_PointSize attribute
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_PointSize,1,gl.FLOAT,false,FSIZE*6,FSIZE*2);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_PointSize);

        // passing data to a_Color attribute
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Color,3,gl.FLOAT,false,FSIZE*6,FSIZE*3);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Color);
        check = true;
    }
    // drawing command to webgl graphics
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS,0,n);
}
```

I am new to WebGL programming, with the above code I wanted to show up a point in a random location inside the canvas after each 10-millisecond intervals, but the program only shows the output at the end of for loop. it doesn't animate the points but shows all points at the end of the animation.
please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is [single threaded and event based](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop). Only one piece of code can run at a time.

You loop

```
    for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){
        points.push(-1+Math.random()*2,1-Math.random()*2,5.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
        n+=1;
        sleep(10);
    }
```

does not let the other event (the requestAnimationFrame) run. Instead your loop runs to completion.

You can fix this in multiple ways.

One is to use `setInterval`

```
var i = 0;

// call the `addPoints` function once every 10ms
var requestId = setInterval(addPoints, 10);

function addPoints() {
  if (i === 1000) {
    clearInterval(requestId);  // stop calling addPoints
    return;
  }

   points.push(-1+Math.random()*2,1-Math.random()*2,5.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
   n+=1;
   ++i;
}
```

or `setTimeout`

```
var i = 0;

function addPoints() {
  if (i === 1000) {
    return;
  }

   points.push(-1+Math.random()*2,1-Math.random()*2,5.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
   n+=1;
   ++i;
   setTimeout(addPoints, 10); // call addPoints in 10ms
}
addPoints(); // add the first point
```

Another is to use [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

```
// make `sleep` function that will work with await
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function addPoints() {
  for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){
    points.push(-1+Math.random()*2,1-Math.random()*2,5.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    n+=1;
    await sleep(10);
  }
}
addPoints();
```

yet another and probably the most common with WebGL would be to add your points in your requestAnimationFrame event

```
    var i = 0;
    var oldTime = 0;

    funcion addPoint() {
      points.push(-1+Math.random()*2,1-Math.random()*2,5.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
      n+=1;
      ++i;
    }

    animate = function(time){
       const deltaTime = time - oldTime;
       if (i < 1000 && deltaTime > 10) {
         oldTime = time;
         addPoint();
       }

        animationID = requestAnimationFrame(animate,canvas);
        draw();
    };
```